# City boundaries for Europe

Tags: city, europe

Is there public data of city boundaries for countries in Europe?

I tried using ArcGIS Online search function but could not find anything.

Comment: Have you tried openstreetmap.org ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what you were looking for but here is the link for you to get there:

http://www.diva-gis.org/

http://www.gadm.org/

http://www.opengeocode.org/opendata/